# Swift - Not declustering when have 2 annotations at the same spot

Tags: swift, mapkit, cluster-computing, overlap

I'm working with MKClusterAnnotation so when one annotation overlaps other, it groups and shows the number of annotations in that specific spot.

But when I have annotations really close to each other it creates the cluster annotation but it doesn't decluster when zooming in. Probably because it is still overlapping each other after reaching the maximum zoom.

I've been trying to find a workaround, relocating the markers within cluster annotation radius but no success.

How to handle when there is 2 or more annotations too close? Any ideas?

Comment: Having the same issue, appears to be a bug. Going to file a Radar at Apple.